# Swift: if the element in a collection view has space to spare, center it

Tags: swift, collectionview

I have a `CollectionView`, and what I want to do is, that last element, as it has space, to center it.

[image]

This is my code, I have the class that inherits from UICollectionView that does not have more than the obligatory methods.

```swift
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (view.frame.size.width/3) - 3,
                                 height: (view.frame.size.width/3) - 3)
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 40, bottom: 40, right: 40)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 40
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 40
        
        let cv = CollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        present(cv, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at implementing the sizeForItemAt delegate function.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // Do your logic here:
    // Find the last item:
    if indexPath.item == YOURARRAY.last {
        // Logic for centering
    }
    return CGSize(width: (view.frame.size.width/3) - 3,
                  height: (view.frame.size.width/3) - 3)
}
```